# Anchor link cutting off the page based on height of absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css

When clicking on an anchor link, it cuts off a portion of the page. Near as I can tell it occurs in all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/PJDWs/

If you go to that fiddle and click on the link at the top, you will notice that you are unable to scroll up to the top of the page. Effectively part of the page has been removed.

There are a couple things that *cause* it, but I don't know why they do. If you remove `overflow: hidden` from the `.bodyContent` then it does not exhibit this behavior. Also, you will notice that the distance of the cut off is exactly equal to the value of `top: XXpx` on `.stuff`. Thus setting `top: 0px` will fix the problem as well.

The issue is that for the specific design I'm working on, neither of these are options as the element needs to be positioned off the top and the parent needs overflow hidden. But more importantly, why is this occurring, and especially why does it occur across all browsers... it almost seems like it's by design.

Comment: If you mean by "scroll up to the top" that, after click, you can't scroll the frame "to the top" (or, up), at least in FF7 (and Chrome) I can do that. The green disappears though.

Comment: because there is a scroll happening inside the `overflow:hidden` element, and no scrollbars appear due to the `hidden` part.

Comment: But why is there a scroll happening inside the overflow hidden? Why is the scroll not happening on the page itself.

Comment: Just for reference some useful info here http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/appendix/equalheightproblems

Also contains test to see if it will happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove the `height:100%;` and replace it with `bottom:0;` it will work because the height, with top and bottom set, is then defined by the enclosing container - it's an interesting bug but this workaround will get the job done.

Comment: Yup. That's it. Your idea of using positions to stretch an element actually makes it size perfectly to it's parent even allowing borders margins and padding, which when using `height: 100%` or `width: 100%` causes problems as they overflow without it. http://jsfiddle.net/NwM6z/1/. Very good find.