# Hash tag links cut off part of a page

Tags: html, anchor

When I link to the middle of a different page using HTML's hash tag upper part of that page gets cut off:

Document 1:

```
<a href="/document2#middle_of_the_page">Test</a>
```

Document 2:

```
<a name="middle_of_the_page">Anchor in the middle of the page</a>
```

like so:

[image: the header got cut off]

Comment: not sure how that's possible, but else give it another name? don't use hash tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016673/anchor-link-cutting-off-the-page-based-on-height-of-absolute-positioned-element