# Anchor link is cutting off top portion of page

Tags: css, anchor

Link to my website: http://gcfpf.com/index.html

When you click on any of the grey circles (informative, for example) it uses an anchor link to to take you to a specific part of another another page. When you click the anchor link, the page it takes you to loses the navigation bar, chops off half of the header image, and pushes the copyright statement at the bottom of the page down about 200 pixels.

Please help!! I am desperate and nothing I try seems to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016673/anchor-link-cutting-off-the-page-based-on-height-of-absolute-positioned-element

Answer (score 0):

On Safari & Firefox on the Mac I'm not seeing this issue. On IE9 in Windows I'm not seeing it either. The anchor link seems to take the user to the appropriate div. One thing to note: On all browsers I'm seeing the copyright at the top right.

That issue seems to be due to the 
`<p style="text-align: center">©2013 The Global Center for Political Finance. All Rights Reserved.</p>` 
being outside of the containing footer div. move it back before the `</div>` for the footer tag and you should be good to go.