# Can't scroll to top after clicking anchor link

Tags: css, wordpress, overflow, anchor

After I click an anchor on this page:
http://somaticstudies.com/resources

I cannot scroll back to the top of the page, and I lose the sidebar content which only appears at the top of the page. I saw this:

[Anchor link cutting off the page based on height of absolute positioned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016673/anchor-link-cutting-off-the-page-based-on-height-of-absolute-positioned-element)

And I tried removing `overflow:hidden` (which would mess up my layout), but it didn't help. I also don't have `height:0` anywhere. I am not sure what is causing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding overflow:scroll helped. It still behaves strangely, but it's good enough for now.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but seems that I have the same behaviour with or without `overflow:scroll` property on `#primary`. That said those `margin:-9999px; padding:9999px;`, you have at several place, are confusing and definitely not a good practice. It will obviously lead you to strange behaviour.

Comment: The reason for the strange margin and padding was to make equal height columns without using tables as seen here: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/equal-height-columns-in-css/. However, I was able to change it on this page and I think my problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove your `margin-bottom:-9999px` on your `#content`

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem indeed but reveal something else is wrong and it will lead to other strange behaviours.